# Iterating over submitted form fields in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

In Flask 0.8, I know I can access individual form fields using `form.fieldname.data`, but is there a simple way of iterating over all the form fields? I'm building an email message body, and I'd like to loop over all the fields and create a fieldname/value entry for each, as opposed to manually building it by naming each field and appending.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suspect that your are using [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

You can iterate over form data:

```
for fieldname, value in form.data.items():
    pass
```

You can iterate over all form fields:

```
for field in form:
    # these are available to you:
    field.name
    field.description
    field.label.text
    field.data
```

Answer (score 16):

The form object has an iterator defined on it:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
    {% if field.type == "BooleanField" %}
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ field }} {{ field.label }}</td>
    {% else %}
        <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ field }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is from https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.type