# How do I efficiency create big forms - FlaskForms

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

So I have an update form end point, which is very large, I've tried a few things to make it dynamically created to condense my code but I cant seem to figure it out.

```py
@customers.route("/<int:customer_id>/update_customer", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# not programmatic - needs work - I do not like this
def update_customer(customer_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(customer_id)
    if post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = CustomerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.tpi_name = form.tpi_name.data
        post.tpi_ref = form.tpi_ref.data
        post.company_name = form.company_name.data
        post.company_type = form.company_type.data
        post.company_reg = form.company_reg.data
        post.sic_code = form.sic_code.data
        post.vat_number = form.vat_number.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("That customer's record has been updated!", 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('customers.view_customer',  customer_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.tpi_name.data = post.tpi_name
        form.tpi_ref.data = post.tpi_ref
        form.company_name.data = post.company_name
        form.company_type.data = post.company_type
        form.company_reg.data = post.company_reg
        form.sic_code.data = post.sic_code
        form.vat_number.data = post.vat_number
    return render_template('customers/customers.html', form=form, username=current_user.username,image_file=current_user.image_file, email=current_user.email)
```

So say if we had 100+ fields in the form, how would I change this code so I don't have to explicitly state each field.

Comment: So, you want to iterate your form fields. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777850/iterating-over-submitted-form-fields-in-flask) will help?

Comment: Looks promising, so how would you structure it in the code?

Comment: A form instance has a [`populate_obj`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) method.

Comment: Looks cool, is there any chance you could write a sample bit of code for its usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [pjcunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800058/pjcunningham)'s answer, and looking into wtform [docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html), I found this piece of code:

```
def edit_profile(request):
user = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['userid'])
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, obj=user)

if request.POST and form.validate():
    form.populate_obj(user)
    user.save()
    return redirect('/home')
return render_to_response('edit_profile.html', form=form)
```

Based on that, I guess you want to write this code:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(post)
    db.session.commit()

    flash("That customer's record has been updated!", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('customers.view_customer',  customer_id=post.id))
```

For the second part of your code (the "GET" branch), it depends on your intentions. You can populate your form with data from object when you create it:

```
form = CustomerForm(obj=post)
```

Comment: Happy to hear that!